# Store variable at the time button is clicked for use when ajaxComplete event fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, event-handling, jquery-events

I have 4 buttons on a page with the same class. When any of these buttons are clicked, an Ajax event is triggered, which I listen for with ajaxComplete. The problem is, if I click a button right after another, the variables assigned to the first one seem to overwrite the second, so the actions intended for the second do not happen.

I attached namespaces specific to the elements to separate ajaxComplete handlers, but this hasn't solved the issue. I'm probably missing or not using something obvious.

The main problem, as I see it, is that I'm storing the IDs based on the last button that was clicked, so when the event is triggered, it's affecting the wrong element. (The most recent variable assigned to `$sheetBlock`). I need to store these variables at the time the button corresponding to the event is clicked.

A few caveats—I can't add any extra properties to the html elements, however, each button and element affected does have its own ID.

I thought storing the `$flippyFunc` function in a var and running when each button is pressed would allow me to store the ID for each button at the time that it is clicked alongside each ajax Event to be used together. How can I do this?

```js
var $id = null;
var $laddaButtons = [];
var $it = null;
var $results = [];
var $sheetBlock = [];

var runOnAjax = function(button, id){
    $(button).off('mousedown.button');
    $sheetBlock[id] = $('#'+button.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id);
};
var $flippyFunc = function($id){
    $sheetBlock[$id].flippy({
    //options
    });
};

$('.ladda-button').on('mousedown.this', function(e) {
    $id = this.id;
    $it = this;
    runOnAjax($it, $id);
    $(document).on("ajaxComplete."+$id, function(e) {
        $(document).off("ajaxComplete."+$id);
        $flippyFunc($id);       
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to pass the variable I needed from the ajaxSend event's settings object through to the corresponding ajaxComplete event's settings object. It was as simple as:

```js
$(document).on("ajaxSend"), function(e, xhr, settings) {
    settings.buttonID = $id;
}
```

And then access the buttonID variable when the corresponding ajaxComplete event is fired:

```js
$(document).on("ajaxComplete"), function(e, xhr, settings) {
    $id = settings.buttonID;

    // Now I can use `$id` as it was when the ajaxSend event was triggered.
}
```